# Search tree with efficient diff for derived trees

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I'm looking for a search tree implementation in Haskell which provides an efficient difference function for trees which share structure.  For example, if I have a large tree `x` (e.g. with millions of elements) and I insert three new elements into it to produce `x'`, I'd like to be able to invoke `difference x x'` to get those elements back, where `difference` is implemented such that the elements of interest are found by only visiting the nodes not shared between the two trees.

The scenario I have in mind is like that of a version control system, where each new version is derived from the previous one, and we may need to find the difference between any two versions.

The data structure should support efficient insertion, deletion, and lookup operations (e.g. O(log n)) as well.

Such an implementation would rely on something like System.Mem.StableName or Data.Unique.Id to label each node in the tree uniquely, allowing the `difference` function to efficiently recognize shared structure and avoid descending into it.

Does something like this exist already?  If not, what's a good strategy for implementing it?  I was thinking of modifying something like Wu Xingbo's RBTree implementation to add unique labels to each node, but I'm open to other options.

Comment: What properties of trees do you need besides this `difference` function? Do you also need fast insertion? membership tests? And what are the types of elements? Are these from an arbitrary type, or an opaque key type that is unique to the tree?

Comment: Yes, I need fast insertion, deletion, and lookup (e.g. O(log n)).  The element types in my case are application-specific record types keyed with `ByteString`s (i.e. I'd be using it as a `Map`, not just as a `Set`), but ideally this would work for any key type that's an instance of `Ord`.

Comment: General `Ord` keys can kill efficiency, in comparison with more structured keys. That is especially true in your case because two equivalent trees may be balanced differently. I imagine tries, PATRICIA trees, etc., could offer much better diff performance.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a single large tree `x` that you want to know the difference to, then
instead of computing the difference, you could track the changes explicitly:

```
-- extend a map with some insertions and deletions
data ExtMap k v = ExtMap { baseMap :: Map k v, changes :: Map k (Maybe v) }

fromMap :: Map k v -> ExtMap k v
fromMap x = ExtMap x Map.empty

toMap :: Ord k => ExtMap k v -> Map k v
toMap (ExtMap x y) = Map.mergeWithKey (\_ _ u -> u) id id x y

lookup :: Ord k => k -> ExtMap k v -> Maybe v
lookup k (ExtMap x y) = case Map.lookup k y of
  Just mv -> mv             -- if there is a change for this key, return that
  Nothing -> Map.lookup k x -- otherwise look in the base map

insert :: Ord k => k -> v -> ExtMap k v -> ExtMap k v
insert k v (ExtMap x y) = ExtMap x (Map.insert k (Just v) y)

delete :: Ord k => k -> ExtMap k v -> ExtMap k v
delete k (ExtMap x y) = ExtMap x (Map.insert k Nothing y)
```

Comment: Thanks, Twan.  That works well for the example I gave, but maybe I should have provided more context in my question.  The scenario I have is similar to a version control system where each new version is derived from the previous one, and I might need to find the differences between any two versions.  So there isn't just one single large tree `x` I need to compare against, but many.  I'll update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and [implemented this](https://github.com/wuxb45/Haskell-RBTree/compare/master...dicej:master?w=0) myself, modifying Wu Xingbo's RBTree to support values annotated with version information which can then be used to calculate a difference efficiently using `diffVersion`.